# Compute Exponentially Weighted Moving Average with a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                   'B': [1,3,2,5,2,0],
                   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,0]
                  })
df 

    A   B   C
0   a   1   1
1   a   3   1
2   a   2   1
3   b   5   1
4   b   2   1
5   b   0   0
```

To compute the exponentially weighted moving average for each group in `A` I can do:

```py
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(halflife=12).mean())

0    1.000000
1    2.028873
2    2.018688
3    5.000000
4    3.456690
5    2.237302
```

With our specified halflife:

[image: alpha]

The computational details are given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows).

What I want to do is to compute the exponentially weighted moving average for each group with a rolling window of 2.

The expected output is:

```py
0    1.000000
1    2.028873
2    2.485563
3    5.000000
4    3.456690
5    0.971127
```

---

This, does not seem to work:

```py
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2).ewm(halflife=12).mean())
```

But, I would like to see a solution involving the `.rolling()` method.

Comment: What's the expected output for this data?